# SyntaxError : Unexpected token '?'

Tags: javascript, strapi

I have that error from this code block

```
const username = comment.user.displayName ?? comment.user.firstName;
```

any help will be much appreciated

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator#browser_compatibility

Comment: Where are you getting this error? In your build chain? In a browser? In Node.js?

Comment: Does your environment support the nullish coalescing operator (`??`)? It's a recent addition to the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [@babel-plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator) to transform the Nullish coalescing operator.

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
const username = comment.user.displayName || comment.user.firstName;
```

or

```
const username = comment.user.displayName ? comment.user.displayName :comment.user.firstName;
```